# Debug assertion with CListBox::GetTopIndex(). Ideas?

Tags: c++, mfc

In my qt based C++ application I am using a lib file. The lib file has a class called Customer class that inherits from CListBox.
Now the problem is then when I call a method in the customer class which it inheried from Clistbox I get an assertion error.
For instance if I call GetTopIndex method of class customer (which it inherits from Clistbox) I get a debug asserion failed error and I end up in `afxwin2.inl` at the statement

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE int CListBox::GetTopIndex() const
    { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return (int)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, LB_GETTOPINDEX, 0, 0); }
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue ? I do have access to the code of the lib file. Is it possible to do some minor modifications to get this working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion error means that you are making the call before the listbox control has been created. (Or after it has been destroyed.)